# Why does useEffect not accept pre-defined functions as its first argument?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

```
useEffect(someFunction(), [])
```

Didn't work

```
useEffect(() => {
    someFunction();
  }, [])
```

Worked

In this code, why does `useEffect` use function expressions as the first argument when the `someFunction` is already a function? I tried directly using `someFunction` as the first argument without the function expression, but it didn't work

Comment: `useEffect(someFunction, [])` would work, depending on how `someFunction` is defined.

Comment: @EmileBergeron is it possible if you could enumerate on that? What about async functions?

Comment: `useEffect` expect a specific type of function that either return `undefined` or another function called at cleanup time. An async function returns a promise, which wouldn't work.

Comment: @EmileBergeron But why does putting an async function inside a function expression like the one above work?

Comment: @RaphaelQuiñones because the arrow function returns void instead of a promise. `() => {someAsyncFunction()}` will not return a promise where as `() => {return someAsyncFunction()}` would.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @NoobLife. Is there a resource where I could read more about this?

Comment: @RaphaelQuiñones MDN Web Docs on [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#:~:text=Async%20functions%20always%20return%20a%20promise.%20If%20the%20return%20value%20of%20an%20async%20function%20is%20not%20explicitly%20a%20promise%2C%20it%20will%20be%20implicitly%20wrapped%20in%20a%20promise.)